# How do effectively use the string data_type in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I tried making this small program that takes input and checks for vowels. If there are vowels then it appends them to a string and returns the size of the string.

My only problem is I can't get it to work using strings. What is the major difference over using character arrays? I can get the program to work using something like:

```
char entered[128];
//and then
char exceptions[11] = "aeiouAEIOU";
```

**Quick question about the above array. When I assign the buffer to 'exceptions' it has to be 11 or the compiler will error. Must I manually account for the NULL termination portion?

If I do something like:

```
if(cPtrI[i] == 'a'){
```

I get an error stating unknown operator '==' ??
I thought '==' was a check operator, and '=' was an assignment operator?

```
no match for 'operator==' in '*((+(((unsigned int)i) * 4u)) + cPtrI) == 'a''|
```

AND, if I do something like: (which I thought was correct, at first)

```
if(*cPtrI[i] == *cPtrJ[j]){
```

I get the same error as above, but referencing unknown operator *:

```
no match for 'operator*' in '**((+(((unsigned int)i) * 4u)) + cPtrI)'|
no match for 'operator*' in '**((+(((unsigned int)j) * 4u)) + cPtrJ)'|
```

I thought the * operator said, in effect, 'what is at' the address of where the pointer is pointing.

So, something like the above would read:

```
If(What is at index I of string 'a' EQUALS What is at index J of string 'exceptions'){
then ..
```

Any help with this one? I learned C a bit before C++, so perhaps this is where my confusing is coming from. It was my understanding the the above code would compare addresses of characters/variables they are pointing to. * indicates 'what is at' while just placing the pointer name would indicate the value the pointer is holding(which is an address of the variable being pointed to). Using &ptrName would be the address of the pointer itself, correct? Where have I gone wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int vowelCheck(std::string a);

int main()
{using namespace std;

    string eString;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
        cin >> eString;
    cout << "There were " << vowelCheck(eString) << " vowels in that string.";
    return 0;
}

int vowelCheck(std::string a)
{using namespace std;

    string exceptions = "aeiouAEIOU";
    string vowels;
    string *cPtrI = &a;
    string *cPtrJ = &exceptions;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        cout << i <<"i\n";
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            cout << j << "j\n";
           // cout << cPtrJ[j];
            if(cPtrI[i] == cPtrJ[j]){ //if index of A equal index of J then
                cout << "Added: " << cPtrJ[j];
                vowels.append(cPtrJ[j]); // append that vowel to the string 'vowels'
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return vowels.size();
}
```

Using my debug tools listed above, the program will only increment through j = 8 then stops. Also, if I even enter an initial string something like AEIOU, it will string go through j = 8. So, it is not seeing the equivalent characters.

What am I doing wrong using strings?

Comment: Isn't this like ten questions in one? Do you have something concrete to ask us?

Comment: `Quick question about the above array. When I assign the buffer to 'exceptions' it has to be 11 or the compiler will error. Must I manually account for the NULL termination portion?` Yes.

Comment: What about `exceptions[] = …` and have the compiler figure out the size for you?

Comment: `I get an error stating unknown operator '==' ?? I thought '==' was a check operator, and '=' was an assignment operator?` There's no match _for the arguments you're giving it_. Same for `*`. You're reading it as "the operator doesn't exist", whereas in fact it means "this operator for this combination of arguments doesn't exist".

Comment: Also, writing `using namespace std;` in a function definition is highly unusual.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use `cPtrI` and `cPtrJ` at all?  Why not just access `a` and `exceptions` directly?  You can still use the brackets to access individual characters in them.

Comment: Yeah, I realize you can index using the name of the arrays. I was just trying to utilize pointers in the program. I can get it to work using character arrays, like I posted above. I was just having trouble making it work using the string data-type.

Comment: You've switched from C char arrays to C++ strings without actually taking advantage of (or noticing) the differences!

Comment: Your goal should be to _minimize_ the use of pointers, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

**Forget about pointers**.

```
string *cPtrI = &a;
string *cPtrJ = &exceptions;

// ...

if(cPtrI[i] == cPtrJ[j]){ //if index of A equal index of J then
```

`cPtrI[i]` is the same as `*(cPtrI + i)`, which would be indexing into an array of `string`.

That's why `cPtrI[i] == 'a'` doesn't compile. `cPtrI[i]` has type `std::string&` (remember, it's indexing into a non-existing array of `std::string`), and `'a'` is a `char`. You can't compare the two.

`std::string` has an indexing operator of its own. Just don't use pointless pointers *and it just works*.

```
if(a[i] == exceptions[j]){
```

Comment: I thought strings were arrays as well(ones that also held characters). So, strings are completely different that character arrays? If I cannot compare indices of character arrays and string arrays then another interesting point arises. What type of data is stored in strings?

Comment: Strings are not arrays. Only arrays are arrays. You should read my answer more carefully. You can compare the elements of a string to the elements of a character array. What you can't compare is an element from an array of strings (which is a string) with an element from an array of characters (which is a character).

Comment: I saw that, I suppose I didn't realize I was creating an array of stings. I learned a bit of C before C++ and this was my first attempt at using them in this language. I was under the impression that I was making a pointer(just as I have used using character arrays) that will increment through the array and compare the two  characters(apparently they both aren't characters though.) I realize using pointers here was unnecessary; I just wanted to make use of them.

Comment: @bden: you're not creating an array of strings, but when you use indexing notation on a pointer that's indexing into an array. And since there's no array at all the end result will not be good. It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I suppose, since you stated that strings are not arrays, that you cannot use pointer indexing? Is there any way to use pointers with strings?

Comment: `string* p` is a pointer to a string, so `p + 1` will be a pointer to the next *string*. `char* p` is a pointer to a character, so `p + 1` gives the next *character*.

Comment: Well, right. I thought I was doing that when I did this: string *cPtrI = &a;   Creating a string pointer and setting it equal to the address of the imported string a. And, further, using i to increment through its value using indexing notation cPtrI[i] .. where i begins at 0 and goes to: a.size()

Comment: @bden you can just index into a an object of type `string`, *without pointers involved*. If you want a `char*` (to, for example, pass into a legacy function) you can use the function `c_str`.

Comment: Of course. Using a[i], or exceptions[j]. I was just attempting to make use of them in the program.

Comment: But, to use pointers with strings is this incorrect?  string *cPtrI = &a;

Comment: Just out of curiosity, because it seems an exact copy of what you posted a moment ago claiming to be the correct syntax for string pointers.

Comment: @bden: what do you mean "to use pointers with strings"? Yes, that syntax gives you a pointer to a string.

Comment: @bden, there is **no reason** to use pointers with a `std::string`. It's unnecessary and only overcomplicates things.

Comment: The OP is getting confused between "a pointer to a `string`" and "a `string` is a pointer to one part of a [conceptual] string". The latter is not true but models the C-string approach.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be counting the number of vowels in a string. Instead of writing out the for loops manually and building up a string, let's use `count_if` to do that. The plan is to create a function object that can detect if a character is a vowel and then use count_if to count the number of vowel characters in the string:

```
struct VowelFinder
{
    bool operator()(char c)
    {
        std::string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
        return vowels.find(c) != std::string::npos;
    }
};

int vowelCheck(const std::string& a)
{
    return std::count_if(a.begin(), a.end(), VowelFinder());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've answered your C-related questions in comments.

As for your usage of `std::string`, you're actually trying to use `std::string*` for some reason. Don't do that. Just use the `std::string`; operator `[]` is overloaded for it to work as-is. At the moment you're treating `cPtrI` as a element of an array of strings.

Comment: Ah, well I suppose that answers some questions. So, you cannot use pointers in the same way with strings that you would with character arrays? I suppose that is just another one of those tedious things to remember.

Comment: @bden: a character array is an array of characters, and you can get a pointer into this array. A `string` is also an array of characters (albeit wrapped up), and you can get an `iterator` (conceptually equivalent to a pointer) into this array... or simply use `char const*` if you wish (using the `.data()` member function of `string`) or simply use indices. `string` is a big class with lot of (redundant) functions.

Comment: @bden: There's nothing tedious about it at all. You can use pointers of strings just fine; you merely _don't want to_. All that faffing about with pointers to characters is only _necessary_ with character arrays; in C++ you don't have to bother, which is _much_ nicer. Otherwise what would the difference be between a `string` and a single `char`?